# Dá erro ao executar essa query no sistema que gera relatórios

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, mysqli, tabela-banco-de-dados

Erro ao executar essa query no sistema de relatório, porém diretamente do banco de dados retorna certo>

> ERRO>>> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist StiJDBCDatabase

A consulta é uma bem simples:

`SELECT cd_ord_com, dt_ord_com, cd_especie, ds_especie  FROM ord_com, especie`

Comment: Não está faltando dados nessa consulta? cade os cruzamentos entre as tabelas?

Comment: Voce não teria que especificar qual campo é de cada tabela e qual é a relação entre elas?

Comment: A consulta está sendo executada no banco de dados correto? Este erro é proveniente disto.

Comment: Este erro ocorre : 1) a tabela não existe , 2) existe mas em outro owner , qualifique owner.tabela ou crie um sinônimo público , 3) sem permissão